# ASP.net returning value from sql proc in an if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, stored-procedures

i have a login box on my form with a submit button , on submit im passing the value through to sql to return a simply yes or no.

I can see the value No as my outcome (pic 1)

however i cannot seem to pull it though to my If statement (pic 2). it only allows my to choose count which is always 1, i need the Yes or no value. something on the lines of

```
  if (Login.Outcome() == "No" )
```

I have read somewhre its within items but need help on how to get this value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REp9s.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRgP8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot seems to indicate that Login is a collection whose [0] element has an Outcome property?

```
if(Login[0].Outcome == "No")
```

Comment: Yes that is correct . I have just tired the above and getting an identifier expected error. Struct system.Int32.

Comment: I had an extra dot in . This worked brill cheers